# SaaS architecture PHP login form

Tags: database, authentication, multi-tenant, saas

I have a straight up question. I am developing a SaaS web application in php. 
I have a database for each user when the user registers to the website.

- I wanted to know how do i go about, in the login form when the user logs in, it automatically selects the correct database. I dont know how to implement this feature and I thought you guys might help me out.

Did not find anything on google.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What type of database? MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) library, you pass in the database name as a string as the last argument, so if you have a session variable called `username`, you can do

```
$database = $_SESSION['username'];
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "db_user", "db_pass", $database);
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats all I needed! :)